# ¿Como hacer una función que se ejecute en un click una tarea y doble click otra tarea diferente con REACT NATIVE?

Tags: react-native

*Por favor ayudame, aqui un ejemplo de lo que quiero lograr*

```
 click = () => {

 //Si es 1 Click ejecutar esta (tarea)

 //Si son 2 Clicks ejecutar otra (tarea)

 }
```

Comment: saludos y bienvenido a la comunidad, te recomiendo leer [ask] pues no solo se debe colocar la duda si no al mismo tiempo lo que haz tratado y los errores obtenidos saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias pero esta mas que claro la ayuda que necesito.

Comment: Arniel es necesario que pongas lo que haz hecho, pues nadie va a hacer el trabajo por ti

Comment: Por eso que en la pregunta que hice, dice COMO HACER porque no lo he hecho, nose como empezar soy novato en React Native, por eso puse un ejemplo muy claro de lo qu quiero lograr.

Comment: El sitio pide mostrar un intento de lo que deseas obtener y los errores que te den, no son mis reglas así funciona SO en español

Comment: Puse el ejemplo para que vean el intento de lo que deseo obtener, y si hay razonamiento ya se sabe cual es el error si se lee bien la pregunta, pero mostrar los errores NO porque no lo he hecho valga la redundancia.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías usar un paquete externo como [react-native-double-click](https://github.com/dwicao/react-native-double-click) o intentar hacerlo manualmente usando alguno de los componentes `Touchable` y guardando el último click y chequeando que no hayan pasado más de 300 milisegundos.

Comment: Esta bien, muchas gracias @Gon ;)